# What is the asymptotic behavior of this system of non-linear ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Given the following system of non-linear ODE's:
$$ \ddot x_i = \frac{\omega_i^2}{x_i\prod\limits_{j=1}^3 x_j},\quad x_i(0)=1,\quad \dot x_i(0)=0,\quad \text{for $i=1,2,3$}$$
I am interested in the asymptotic behavior. From numerical integration it seems that as $t\rightarrow\infty$ the asymptotic behavior is linear, i.e. $x_i(t)\sim\alpha_it$. Particularly, how do the proportionality constants $\alpha_i$ depend on the parameters $\omega_i$?

In the case where $\omega=\omega_1=\omega_2=\omega_3$ the system has a symmetry, and $x(t)=x_1(t)=x_2(t)=x_3(t)$ satisfies
$$ \ddot x = \frac{\omega^2}{x^4},\quad x(0)=1,\quad \dot x(0)=0,$$
which can be solved to find that $x(t)\sim\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\omega t$. The question is how this result generalizes to the case were the $\omega_i$ are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Let us introduce the (scaled) functions $y_i$ with
$$x_i = \frac{\omega_i}{(\prod_{j=1}^3 \omega_j )^{1/5}} y_i\;.$$

In terms of these, the equation assume the symmetric form
$$\ddot y_i = \frac{1}{y_i \prod_{j=1}^3 y_j} $$
for which your analysis applies.

Note however that the solution with $y_i = y$ that you have found is not the most general solution to the equation and that you need to find an argument why/if the solutions with arbitrary initial conditions will behave symmetrically for asymptotically long times.

Comment: Thanks for showing the useful transformation. However, the problem is only symmetric if the initial conditions are. After the transformation they no longer are, and so the question remains what its asymptotic behavior is.